# Заполнить матрицу случайными числами

Tags: java, матрицы

Имеется следующий код:

```
private void massiveGet() {
    i = Integer.parseInt(elemNumbers.getText());
    int count = 0;
    while (count < i) {
        count++;
        int number = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
        matrixData.add(new Massive(number));
    }

    System.out.println(matrixData);
}
```

Необходимо заполнить коллекцию `Observable List` согласно введенному числу `i`, допустим, вводится число 5, заполняется коллекция как матрица 5*5

Comment: ...вопрос в чем?

Comment: да вот алгоритм какой? не могу понять

Comment: чтоб обсервабл лист заполнятся ка 5*5 а у меня только 5

Comment: Что у вас за класс `Massive`? Почему его конструктор принимает только одно число?

Comment: Класс массив-это pojo модель с геттерами/сеттерами

Comment: Я ещё не продумал как было бы правильно

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял вопрос, то у Вас, получается не матрица, а то же количество значений, которое задается потому,что у вас цикл отрабатывает i количество раз, что бы получилась матрица необходимо в условие цикла передавать квадрат необходимого значения.
Ваш вариант:

```
i = Integer.parseInt(elemNumbers.getText());
int count = 0;
while (count < i) {
```

т.е. если i = 5 он и отработает 5 раз.
тут необходимо либо перед условием цикла умножать переданное число само на себя
i *= i; т.е.:

```
i = Integer.parseInt(elemNumbers.getText());
int count = 0;
i *= i;
while (count < i) {
```

либо реализовать через 2 цикла:

```
class example {
    int count;
    private void massiveGet() {
        count = Integer.parseInt(elemNumbers.getText());
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
             for(int k = 0; k < count; k++){
                int number = (int) (Math.random() * 100);
                matrixData.add(new Massive(number));
             }
        //Здесь можно организовать перенос строки в матрице
        }
    System.out.println(matrixData);
    }
}
```

На мой взгляд, второй вариант удобнее, с той точки зрения, что при необходимости можно сделать сброс определенных значений при "переносе строки".